# QGIS Rule Based Labeling filter string from a value

Tags: qgis, labeling, filter, string, rule-based

I'm relatively new to QGIS. Recently I started mapping the hiking trails of Nepal. I used a GPX recorder application from Android Play Store. While entering the waypoint, I entered the name. The entered waypoint is in the Name section of the record. I have used a unique name for different types of waypoints.

- Node - Junction
- POI - Point of interests
- Road - Change in type of path.

Example : Node 3 1 correct 2 hiking trail

I want to filter the nodes by filtering the string 'Node'. How could I do that?

Comment: Are Node, POI, Road etc different attribute fields, or is 'Node 3 1 correct 2 hiking trail' one continuous string?

Comment: It is one continuous string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a point layer with a field name `Name` labeled as follows:

[image]

To filter the labels, you need to go to `Rendering (Last tab with brush icon) → Show label →　Edit`, and replace the word `NULL` with the following expression:

```
"Name" like 'Node%'
```

Replace "Name" with the field name that holds the name of the field that you want to display their labels.

The expression means selecting all labels that start with the word `Node`. If you have the word `Node` in the middle of the text, just add another percent character before the word `Node` to become

```
"Name" like '%Node%'
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for the syntax. I used the rule based labelling using the syntax. Can you tell me where I can learn about the Operators.

Comment: @ujjwalbasnet If the answer solved your problem, please accept the answer so that it can help others. 
To learn about the operators, please check the QGIS documentation, it has everything you need.